# DDD: Large Aggregate Root - Person

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I am building a system to manage person information. I have an ever growing aggregate root called Person. It now has hundreds of related objects, name, addresses, skills, absences, etc.  My concern is that the Person AR is both breaking SRP and will create performance problems as more and more things (esp collections) get added to it.

I cannot see how with DDD to break this down into smaller objects. Taking the example of Absences. The Person has a  collection of absence records (startdate, enddate, reason). These are currently managed through the Person (BookAbsence, ChangeAbsence, CancelAbsence). When adding absences I need to validate against all other absences, so I need an object which has access to the other absences in order to do this validation.

Am I missing something here? Is there another AR I have not identified? In the past I would have done this via an "AbsenceManager" service, but would like to do it using DDD.

I am fairly new to DDD, so maybe I am missing something.

Many Thanks....

Comment: Maybe an `Absence` is another AR. What are the invariants you need to enforce through `Person`on the absences?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed what makes aggregate design so tricky.  Ownership does not necessarily mean aggregation.  One needs to understand the domain to be able to give a proper answer so we'll go with the good ol' `Order` example.  A `Customer` would not have a collection of `Order` objects.  The simplest rule is to think about deleting an AR.  Those objects that *could* make sense in the absence of the AR probably do not belong on the AR.  A `Customer` may very well have a collection of `ActiveOrder` objects, though.  Of course there would be an invariant stating that a customer cannot be deleted if it has active orders.

Another thing to look out for is a bloated bounded context.  It is conceivable that you could have one or more bounded contexts that have not been identified leading to a situation where you have an AR doing too much.

So in your case you may very well still be interested in the `Absence` should the `Customer` be deleted.  In the case of an `OrderLine` it has no meaning without its `Order`.  So no lifecycle of its own.

Hope that helps ever so slightly.

Comment: i am a bit late to the party but reading your answer i have a question: what sense does `Order` make if `Customer` is deleted?  For now, lets leave aside obvious business rule that you would never allow deleting of a `Customer` that has at least one `Order`. Point is, `Order` is pretty much meaningless without a `Customer` (noone to pay it, noone to deliver it to, etc...) just like `OrderItem` is without `Order`. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @dzg With this logic, You can say that the Order has no meaning without the Product, so it should be under the Product aggregate. The Order has a meaning of its own. Don't misunderstand the "required" relationship with the "meaningfulness" relationship. Deletion of customers does not necessarily affect the Orders. I mean that the Order has just a snapshot of who bought what. In general, orders do not depend on customers or products. But in the case of active Orders, it is not allowed to delete the corresponding customer.

Answer (score 1):

The **Absence** chould be modeled as an aggregate. An **AbsenceFactory** is reposible for validating against other **Absence** s when you want to add a new **Absence**.

Code example:

```
public class AbsenceFactory {
    private AbsenceRepository absenceRepository;
    public Absence newAbsenceOf(Person person) {
         List<Absence> current = 
              absenceRepository.findAll(person.getIdentifier());
         //validate and return
    }
}
```

You can find this pattern in the blue book (section 6.2 Factory if I'm not mistaken)

In other "modify" cases, you could introduce a **Specification**

```
public class SomeAbsenceSpecification {
    private AbsenceRepository absenceRepository;

    public SomeAbsenceSpecification(AbsenceRepository absenceRepository) {
        this.absenceRepository=absenceRepository;
    } 

    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Absence absence) {
          List<Absence> current = 
              absenceRepository.findAll(absence.getPersonIdentifier());
         //validate and return
    }
}
```

You can find this pattern in the blue book(section 9.2.3 Specification)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but, in addition to @EbenRoux's notes, a huge aggregate root usually means the context mapping is not well done. The fear of fractured entities and integrating data between the bounded contexts leads to a huge aggregate root.

You pour different concerns into your aggregate root just to make sure everything is consistent. So you break the single responsibility rule and make your model fragile by lowering its cohesion.

I think part of your Person model should be in a Context named ProfileContext that manages the general information. Another part should be in the AttendanceContext, and so on.

Answer (score -4):

> I am building a system to manage person information.

Are you sure that a simple CRUD application that edit/query RDBMS's tables via SQL, wouldn't be a cheaper approach?

If you can express the most of the business rules in term of data relations and table operations, you shouln't use DDD at all.

> I have an ever growing aggregate root called Person.

If you actually have complex business rules, an ever growing aggregate is often a syntom of undefined (or wrongly defined) [context boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20118492/412808).