# DDD Repository and Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have some big Entity. Entity has propertis "Id", "Status" and others.
I have Repository for this Entity.
I want to change status in one entity.
Should I get whole Entity, change property Status and use save method in Repository or should I use method ChangeStatus(id, newStatus) in Repository?

Comment: The former one. ChangeStatus(id, newStatus) in Repository makes the entity no sense.

Comment: I mean, using ChangeStatus(id, newStatus) in Repository I don't get whole Entity constructing it from many tables, I just change one Property.

Comment: But the business rule leaks to the persistence layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Probably* you don't need a domain model. You could try a [transaction script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) that directly use SQL to update the database.

You need a domain model if and only if you need to hire an expert to understand the business.
Otherwise, it's just expensive [buzzwords driven development](http://epic.tesio.it/2013/04/18/stupidity-considered-harmful.html).

And btw, if you have big entity classes containing data that you don't need during most of operations, then you know that you haven't properly defined [context boundaries](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/11/ddd-bounded-contexts.aspx).

The best definition of bounded context is the one of Evans:

> The delimited applicability of a particular model. BOUNDING CONTEXTS gives team members a clear and shared understanding of what has to be consistent and what can develop independently.

That is: you have to split the domain expert knowledge in contexts where each term has an **unambiguous meaning** and a restricted set of responsibility. If you do so, you'll obtain small types and modules with high cohesion an